# btrfs error checking when copying files between btrfs HDDs?

Tags: linux, btrfs

If I have two separate USB HDDs with btrfs (both single-mode, no DUP nor RAID) and copy a file from one HDD to another, does btrfs ensure that the copied file is still identical to the original file, based on its btrfs file checksum?

So I can rest assured that if there were no errors reported when copying a bunch of files from one btrfs HDD to another btrfs HDD, they are all ok?

Note that I am unsure if e.g. the "cp" command in itself does some basic checking that nothing gets changed during the copy process, be it a RAM error or USB misbehaving or whatever, one bit just getting flipped during the copy process for a reason or another. I've understood elsewhere that e.g. scp (copying files over the network) does such internal checking, but if btrfs does that too automatically, it is an extra assurance.

Meaning that I don't have to e.g. manually compare the md5 or sha256 checksums of the copied files to the originals just to be sure they are still identical, as btrfs does that already with its own checksums, automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The source btrfs filesystem only knows that you're reading a file, the target only knows that you're writing a file. Source will detect problems when the file is read, target when the file is written, but btrfs doesn't care what happens between them.

`scp` can be used for local transfers too, but [it doesn't offer integrity checks](https://serverfault.com/questions/289646/scp-is-a-checksum-required) (TCP does check integrity in transit over the network, but it doesn't guarantee that stream's input is identical to what you've read and what you're writing is identical to stream's output).

`rsync` [always uses checksums](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30970/53467) but these are in-transit checksums too, in other words it verifies that the file that was *received* matches original, but doesn't check that the file *written* does. You can run `rsync` again with `-c` option to force before-the-transfer checksum calculation. If the checksum matches, the copy will be skipped, otherwise `rsync` will try again.

`md5sum` and `sha1sum` are available too for manual hash comparison.

If your use case here is backup, consider using [btrfs snapshots](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup). These do guarantee integrity on btrfs level and should be more efficient than regular file copy.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that explains it fully. I was hoping there was such an automatic checksum checking with copy operations too, as long as both source and target filesystems utilize btrfs.
It may be it was indeed rsync and not scp which I read having the integrity check between the source and target. In Windows I've sometimes used "TeraCopy" which does the same, checks that the checksums of the source and the target match when copying or moving files.

Comment: So, yeah, I guess I just need to remember to use rsync as much as possible in Linux, just to be sure.

Comment: @timppu If your use case here is backup, consider using [btrfs snapshots](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup). These do guarantee integrity on btrfs level.

Comment: Ok I will read more about the different options to btrfs, maybe that snapshot way is the better way to keep the secondary archive up to date.
As for rsync, I got the impression from the other discussion that in order to be fully sure that the copied files match, you actually have to run rsync twice in a row, with "rsync -c" the second time. So it apparently doesn't check that the copied file matches, after the copy operation, so that is why the "second round" would be needed.

Comment: @timppu You're right, answer updated!